# Yasoon - Modify existing email, replace file with http(s) share link

Tags: outlook, cloud, email-attachments

Can the Yasoon Outlook development system modify existing emails, so that I could replace all attachments with links to the file from our internal cloud storage environment?

Or does anyone know of an app that will let me do this?  I have seen the ones for Box/Dropbox/etc, but we are using FileCloud, and they have a very rich API in addition to the storage being hosted internally.

What the company would like to do is the following:

1. Select attachments by criteria
2. Upload the attachment(s) to FileCloud (FileCloud API)
3. Set the file as shared, with the mailfile owner being the only
   authorized user (FileCloud API)
4. Replace the file in the email with the new share URL from FileCloud

   And continue on until all selected attachments have
   been processed in the mail file.

Answer (score 0):

Tobi from Yasoon here, sorry for not getting back earlier.
Our tool is probably overblown for this use case though it's possible (https://github.com/yasoonOfficial/com.yasoon.attachment.export)

But you should probably look into the new Outlook API: https://dev.outlook.com/MailAppsGettingStarted/GetStarted